# Laravel 5 form validation of array on different

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

from request I get an array like this:

```
'array' => [
    0 => ['id' => 1,'val' => 2],
    1 => ['id' => 1,'val' => 2]
]
```

I need to validate it so all ids of array will be unique.
right now I try this validation rule:

```
'array.*.id' => 'different:array.*.id'
```

but it will check current array with current array so result will be like

```
The array.0.id and array.0.id must be different.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [distinct](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-distinct) rule:

```
'array.*.id' => 'distinct'
```

Comment: I was around it and needed only be right with these symbols, thanks